# WriteToFile Problem in iPhone with Model Class

Tags: iphone, lazy-loading

I have problem in WriteToFile in iPhone LazyLoading application.
One of my project i am using lazyloading in that project i want to cache all data in to document directory

in that entry NSArray object containing AppRecored model class objects so i want to write entry NSArray in to Document Directory.

I know the WriteToFile is write the plist file so all the object are NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString and NSNumber but is there any chance to store that array containing model class.

Please let me know your comments...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for NSKeyedArchiver & NSKeyedUnArchiver...